# How to Generate UUID while creating record through Adonis Lucid ORM model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, uuid, adonis.js

**TL;DR**

I want Lucid ORM alternative to following PGSQL Query

```
INSERT INTO "api_logs" ("request_id", "request_url", "request_method", "request_data", "response_data", "remark", "created_at", "updated_at")
VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), NULL, 'POST', '{
    "test": "success"
}', '{
    "test": "success"
}', 'test', now(), now());
```

I am using PostgresSQL with Adonis Node Framework, I have a table named `api_logs` with following schema:

```
id  integer Auto Increment [nextval('api_request_logs_id_seq')] 
request_id  uuid    
request_url character varying(255) NULL 
request_method  character varying(255) NULL [POST]  
request_data    json NULL   
response_data   json NULL   
created_at  timestamptz NULL    
updated_at  timestamptz NULL
```

I am trying to create a record using Adonis Lucid ORM, but it is returning exception.

**Failed attempts:**

```
await ApiRequestLog.create({
  request_id : uuid.v4(),
  request_url : request.url(),
  request_method : request.method(),
  request_data : request.all(),
  response_data : response_data,
  remark : 'Test Request with success response'
});
```

**Error:**
uuid is not defined

```
await ApiRequestLog.create({
  request_url : request.url(),
  request_method : request.method(),
  request_data : request.all(),
  response_data : response_data,
  remark : 'Test Request with success response'
});
```

**Error:**

null value in column "request_id" violates not-null constraint

Thanks in advance!!!

Best.

Comment: Please include exception message, detail, hint and context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After racking my brain, I could not find the solution with Adonis JS but I figured out the way by doing changes in PostgresQL.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Alter Table to add UUID while running

```
ALTER "request_id" TYPE uuid,
ALTER "request_id" SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
ALTER "request_id" SET NOT NULL;
COMMENT ON COLUMN "api_logs"."request_id" IS '';
COMMENT ON TABLE "api_logs" IS '';
```

Worked for me, hope this will work for everyone.